# How to disable Anti-Aliasing for JavaFX Fonts?

Tags: javafx

I'm making an overlay for a game with JavaFX by putting information on a magenta colored background and ColorKeying it out in OBS.
However, due to the Edges of the Font "mixing" with the background, It can't be properly keyed out (I can't change the parameters of the color key without keying out part of the Overlay).
Is there a way to disable Anti-aliasing for Fonts?
[The problem can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz5Az.png)

Comment: Why don't you render directly onto a transparent surface?

Comment: I'm kind of new to javaFX - i know that without a background, the window just has a grey/white background - I'm not sure how to make it transparent, but would appreciate help.

Comment: I wonder if changing the [`fontSmoothingType`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#fontSmoothingTypeProperty) would help you? If you're using a `Label` node instead of a `Text` node you _may_ be able to change this with CSS, though the reference guide doesn't document the substructure of a `Label`.

Comment: As far as I understand your problem you don't have to care for window background. You could just render into a Canvas (with a transparent background) and take a snapshot of it and store it as a PNG.

Comment: I've tried making the background transparent, and although it worked, OBS does not support transparanecy with Window Capture, and Game capture doesn't work with javaFX.